# Element is not allowed

Tags: xml, xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2002/xml-events">
   <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <xf:model>
            <xf:instance xmlns="">
                <User>
                    <username/>
                    <password/>
                </User>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:bind id="user" nodeset="/User/username"></xf:bind>
            <xf:bind id="password" nodeset="/User/password"></xf:bind>
        </xf:model>


    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've got this xhtml file and is always getting the error:

> element xf:model is not allowed here. Expecting element end of tag...

Can me explain what i'm doing wrong? I'm a beginner at xhtml.

Comment: xforms? Didn't that die alongside XHTML 2?

Comment: [Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-xforms-20031014/sliceG.html) is an official W3C page with complete Xforms examples, but those examples won't work either. The browsers can't handle them, knowing nothing about the XHTML 2 namespace, and the W3C validator gives out the same errors as with your example.